# Formatting Progress Bar in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

Using Bootstrap 4, I have set up a progress bar, located under the navbar, that displays how far down the page you have scrolled. However, I am having an issue with the formatting.  Specifically, there is a space between it and the left side of the page.  Please see below:

[image: Progress Bar with space between it and the left side of page]

My html code is:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar w/ text</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="navbar-text">
    Navbar text with an inline element
  </span>
</div>
```

For my css:

```
body {

    padding: 0 2%;

}

.progress {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.progress-bar {

    position: fixed;
    height: 2rem;
    color: white;
    font-weight: $fw-700;
    font-size: $fs-200;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

In addition, all content is contained in section tags, with the class of content, that has the following formatting:

```
.content {

      padding: 2rem;
      font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
      font-size: clamp(2.1rem, 2.3rem, 2.5rem);
      font-weight: 500;
      position: relative;
      border: 5px solid #090160;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background-color: #f9fafb;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1rem #d4d1ff;
              box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1rem #d4d1ff;
}
```

I hav also tried setting using:

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12"></div>
 </div>
```

and adjusting the width of the column (col-10, col-8 for example) with no change.

How to I format the progress bar so it stretches across the entire page or is the width of the sections that follow it?

Comment: Remove body sides padding 2%

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the padding did not fix the issue.  It still looks the same as the image it the question.